# In Python, how do I create a visual data of my output represented on a number line?

Tags: python

I just picked up Python as my second language a few days ago and I managed to create a little program that asks the user for a random number and the computer generates random numbers until that random number equals the user's number.

```
import random
import time

print("Enter a random number. I will try to find it")
password = int(input() )

start = time.time()
for i in range(2 ** 10):
    rand_num = random.randint(0, 100)
    if rand_num == password:
        print("Number found!", password)
        end = time.time()
        print(" It took", end - start, "seconds to find the number")
        break
    else:
        print(rand_num, "is not the number")
```

To step things up, I want to create like a visual representation of all the randomly generated numbers on a number line.

Something like this:

[image]

I have tried looking on Google but haven't gotten any success. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, but please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help. You need to include some code or show research effort when asking questions.

Comment: There's a problem with your code. You should prompt the user to enter a number between 0 and 100 and check the value entered. What would happen to your program if I entered the value 101?

Comment: Do you want that display to be in a graphic screen, or would a text screen, such as a Python console, suffice? And do you want the values grouped by 5s, as in your example, or do you want all values shown separately? By the way, the "70" in your graphic example is incorrectly shown as "07".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the values generated while searching for the number entered by the user.

Have a read about lists and dictionaries. You could store in a `list` all the numbers generated while searching, and then aggregate the results for display once you find it.

Or you could use a dictionary to store a count of the numbers that fall in to ranges such as 0-10, 10-20, etc.

Creating the graph would be another question all together. Have a go at solving the first part, aggregating the results, and then worry about the visual display.